# How to group Select2 Tags in different categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I would like to group the resulting Tags after they have been selected in different categories like:

```
Cat1: 
   Tag1 
   Tag2
   ...
 Cat2
   Tag4
   Tag5
   ...
```

I tried this approach so far:

```
        var counter = 0;
        var select2 = $(".category-entity-tags").select2({
        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
        insertTag: function (data, tag) {
            
            if (data.length) data = new Array(1000);

            if (counter < 10) data[counter + 1] = tag;
            if (counter > 5) data[counter + 100] = tag;
            
           counter++;
        }
    });
```

but this looks to not give me control over the tag html elements or over the template and for some reasons it's fired every time I type something and not only when the tag is created..

Comment: can you create working demo code ?

Comment: i'm stuck on this so far. As I have an update I´ll push it but my idea is to reorder the tags so i can style them and insert on every set of tags a category TITLE.